# Maximum Input Wattage of MFJ-1717PL Antenna

Tags: antenna, mobile

I was wondering if anybody knew the maximum input wattage of the MFJ-1717PL Antenna. I was going to use this with the Yaesu FT-1900R mobile radio mounted in a Pelican case.

Comment: Try [asking the manufacturer](http://www.mfjenterprises.com/custsupport.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The antenna is specifically marketed for mobile and base station use, so I expect it to readily handle 20-50W without issue.  However, the manufacturer doesn't publish power specifications, and after looking at a few dozen reviews, sellers, and forums it appears that many have asked for this information and it has never been provided.  The reviews are generally good, but again no mention of power - however no mention of overheated antennas or damaged transceivers either.

It's an inexpensive enough antenna that if you're willing to experiment, then it's probably worth trying out at 20W for five minutes of solid transmission, then turn the transmitter off and check the antenna temperature along its length, particularly at any locations with components or connections.

If it isn't warm, try it at 55W and check the temperature.  If it's not warming up appreciably, you might be safe at those transmitter levels.

If, however, you don't want to experiment or need more assurance that it won't fail spectacularly later, you should look for an antenna with a guaranteed manufacturer rated power handling capability.